# How to import terrain models properly?

Tags: import

I'm complete beginner in blender...I'm trying to import mountain 3D model but the edges are cutting off...is there any way to bring those edges down? [image]

Comment: Is it a model, I mean a real mesh that is displaced like this or are you using a height map for displacement? That would be interesting to know for answering this question. If it's a real mesh you can go with the answer by @moonboots

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, you could select all the border, activate the *Proportional Editing* option, make sure that the influence sphere is large enough...

[image]

then <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to flatten on Z (you'll still be able to adjust the proportional size in the *Operator* box):

[image]

Comment: It worked thanks for helping me!